# node.js nested asynchronous function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, nested

it's me again. I have an issue here with nested asynchronous functions that do not provide the result expected.

I have the below code, which shall get all json-files from a directory and then, for each file, get some information from within this file. Finally the whole use of this getTagList, is to get a list of json-files together with information on these files, obtained from within the files.

The first function is standard fs.readdir, whereas the 2nd function is my own getTagData = function(app, tagId, callback).

Both do work without problems, but the final result I want (that is the list of json-files plus information on the content of these files) is not correctly provided in the final callback.

See my code here:

```
var getTagList = function(app, callback){
  // get global app variables
  var DEBUG = app.get('DEBUG');
  var TRACE = app.get('TRACE');

  var svrProto = app.get('svrProto');
  var svrAddr = app.get('svrAddr');
  var svrPort = app.get('svrPort');
  var svrApi = app.get('svrApi');

  var rfidTagDir = app.get('rfidTagDir');

  if (DEBUG) console.log('function getTagList called');

  var responseContent = '';

  try {
    fs.readdir(rfidTagDir, function(err, items) {
      if (DEBUG) console.log('working on directory ' + rfidTagDir);

      if (err) {
        // irgendein Fehler beim einlesen des Verzeichnisses
        console.error("error: error occured trying to read directory "+rfidTagDir + '\n   error message: ' + err.toString());
        // '{\'response\': \'error\', \'message\': \'error getting files from directory '+rfidTagDir+'\', \'exception\': \''+err.toString()+'\'}'
        var errCallback = {
          response: 'error',
          message: 'error getting files from directory ' + rfidTagDir,
          error: err.toString()
        };

        callback(errCallback);
      } else if (!items.length) {
        // directory appears to be empty
        console.warn("warning: nothing to read in directory "+rfidTagDir);
        //'{\'response\': \'warning\', \'message\': \'nothing to read from directory '+rfidTagDir+'\'}'
        var errCallback = {
          response: 'warning',
          message: 'nothing to read from directory '+rfidTagDir
        };

        callback(errCallback);
      } else {
        // im Verzeichnis sind tatsaechlich Dateien
        if (DEBUG) console.log('Anzahl Elemente im Verzeichnis '+rfidTagDir+': ' + items.length);
        responseContent = "{\'tags\': ["

        //var respCallback = { tags: []};
        var tagItemArray = [];

        for (i in items) {
          if (items[i].toString().substr(items[i].indexOf('.')) == '.json') {
            if (DEBUG) console.log('Arbeite auf item ' + items[i]);
            var dirItem = '';

            // tag-id auslesen, da wir sie gleich brauchen
            var tag = items[i].toString().toUpperCase().substring(0,items[i].indexOf('.'));
            //\'title\': \'" + tagTitle + "\',
            responseContent += "{\'tag\': \'" + tag + "\', \'endpoint\': \'"+svrAddr+':'+svrPort+svrApi+"/tags/tag/" + tag + "\', \'file\': \'"+items[i]+"\'}";

            getTagData(app, tag, function(err, result){
              if (err) {
                console.error('error: could not retrieve tag data for tag ' + tag);
                /*
                dirItem = {
                  tag: tag,
                  endpoint: svrProto+'://'+svrAddr+':'+svrPort+svrApi+'/tags/tag/'+tag,
                  title: 'no tag info - error: ' + err.toString()
                };
                */
              } else {
                if (DEBUG) console.log('data for tag ' + tag + ' retrieved')
                if (TRACE) console.log(dirItem);

                var obj = result;

                dirItem = {
                  tag: tag,
                  endpoint: svrProto+'://'+svrAddr+':'+svrPort+svrApi+'/tags/tag/'+tag,
                  title: obj.MediaTitle,
                  genre: obj.MediaGenre,
                  type: obj.MediaType,
                  disks: obj.DiskCount,
                  tracks: obj.TrackCount
                };
                tagItemArray.push(dirItem);
              }
            });

            //tagItemArray.push(dirItem);

            // we only need to add the , after an array element in the json
            // structure, if there are sukzessive elements.
            if (i<items.length-1) responseContent += ",";
          } else {
            if (DEBUG) console.log('ignoring file ' + items[i] + ' as it is not a json file');
          }
        }
        responseContent += "]}"
      }
      if (DEBUG) console.log('taglist ready, providing via callback');
      var respCallback = {
        tags: tagItemArray
      };
      if (TRACE) console.log(respCallback);
      callback(null, respCallback);
    });
  } catch (ex) {
    console.error("could not read directory "+rfidTagDir+" to list available tags \nException output: " + err.toString());
    //'{\'response\': \'error\', \'message\': \'could not read directory '+rfidTagDir+'\', \'exception\': \' '+err.toString()+'\'}'
    var errCallback = {
      response: 'error',
      message: 'could not read tags from directory ' + rfidTagDir,
      error: ex.toString()
    };
    callback(errCallback);
  }
}
```

Can anyone tell me, why the inner function call to getTagData() is not providing the results in time, so that the generated (best of course combined) callback of the try-block includes the results from getTagData???

Best regards,

Christian

Comment: Have you tried promises?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but I suggest using a library that promisifies the fs library, like https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-extra . This will make navigating, debugging and understanding your code so much easier.

Comment: You can also use [promisify](http://2ality.com/2017/05/util-promisify.html) so it will be easier to handle your processes.

Comment: What is the `getTagData` function? Since it has a callback I can only assume it is asynchronous I/O non-blocking, and so what happens is you have `getTagData` called `i` times from your loop, and then they all eventually get the callback function called, but by that time your main callback `callback(null, respCallback);` has already been called. You can do something like using a counter and a while loop to wait for all of them... but it's better just to use an async package  or switch to promises or async/await.

Comment: Thanks all for the replies. I was more or less sure that the nested functions are a problem. I would, however try to stick to the callback functionality for now. As I'm still learning I would rather progress in somewhat small steps. So, given that both functions (gems.readfir and my own getTagData are written as asynchron functions with callbacks, is there any way to guarantee the data from the json-files are retrieved prior to the outer callback being fired?